# Vert.x OIDC Lite Access Token

Tags: openid-connect, vert.x

I am trying to request an access token via OIDC Lite on a AWS <> AWS basis.

On the server side there's already a configuration for the token generation where issuer is provided.

I am curious how can I configure the `OAuth2WebClient` so that I can retrieve the token and make requests based on the access URI and Resource server and scopes?

```
   public void dummyFraudCheckWithOidcLite() {
    LOGGER.info("Request access");
    OAuth2Auth oauth2 = OAuth2Auth.create(vertx, new OAuth2Options());
    OAuth2WebClient.create(webClient, oauth2)
            .get("https://localhost:8080/test")
            .send(ar -> {
                if (ar.succeeded()) {
                    HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
                    LOGGER.info("Got HTTP response with status " + response.statusCode());
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Fail", ar.cause());
                }
            });

}
```

Thanks.